# does "it will be great if you do this for me" sound arrogant or impolite?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I learned that the future real conditional "**it will be great if you do this for me**" (1) means you think it is very likely to happen.

And the present or future unreal conditional "**it would be great if you did this for me**" (2) means you think it is not very likely to happen.

When I talk to some native speakers, sometimes I feel they frown when they hear the **(1)**.

As a native speaker, do you think the speaker is arrogant or very impolite when he says "**it will be great if you do this for me**" instead of "**it would be great if you did this for me**"?

Comment: The first one feels like bad English to me, and unless the person has already agreed to do it, it sounds presumptuous on top of that. "It would be great if you did..." is totally natural, and I recommend using it only

Comment: @gotube, "**sound presumptuous**" means arrogant?

Comment: Not exactly. Oxford says: "*(of a person or their behaviour) failing to observe the limits of what is permitted or appropriate.*" To your example, "sounds presumptuous" means that it sounds like I'm assuming you will help me even though you haven't agreed to yet. Being presumptuous can be a sign of arrogance, but they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @gotube, but when I apply for a job and if I said "**it will be great if you give me a chance**". It is clear that  "**I'm assuming the interviewer will help me even though he hasn't agreed to yet.**". Isn't that mean "**arrogant**"?

Comment: There's different reasons for someone to be presumptuous. One of them is arrogance. Another is not understanding social norms. Either way, that sentence sounds really unnatural to me and I wouldn't use it at all.